# How to process data of any time interval in window in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Look at picture below:

[image]

There are **'time1'**,**'time2'**,**'time3'** in window, can I process only **'time2'** and filter other 'time'(discard 'time1','time3')?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to process one Dstream of data at a time, don't use window functions.  Windows work by combining multiple Dstreams together and then processing the data.

You can process just the data at 'time1', then when 'time2' comes in, you can just process that data.  Seems like you're overly complicating what you're trying to do based on the description.

An example:

```
yourDStream = //your reciever
yourDStream.map(...).foreach(//save somewhere)
```

The code above will only apply your transformation to the current Dstream.  By applying a window, you're telling spark to aggregate multiple dstreams together.  If you don't use the window functions, then you won't have to worry about discarding data from your window.